# How to assert JSON 2D array using RestAssured?

Tags: java, junit, rest-assured, hamcrest

Using RestAssured and I am truggling to assert on a 2D String array in the response body.  I have response JSON as:

```
{
    "status": {
        "code": "00",
        "message": "SUCCESS",
        "timestamp": "2021-06-14T11:25:34Z"
    },
    "data": {
        "data": [
            [
                "elementZero",
                "elementOne",
                "elementTwo"
            ]
        ]
    }
}
```

And my code is as follows

```
    given()
            .auth().oauth2(token)
            .when()
            .pathParam("orderId", orderId)
            .get("/getScreeningsForOrder/{orderId}")
            .then()
            .statusCode(200)
            .contentType(ContentType.JSON)
            .assertThat()
            .body("data.data[0]", arrayContainingInAnyOrder("elementZero", "elementOne", "elementTwo"))
            .body("status.code", equalTo("00"))
            .body("status.message", equalTo("SUCCESS"))
            .body("status.timestamp", Matchers.startsWith(expectedTimestamp_yyyyMMdd))
            .extract()
            .response();
```

I get the following error:

> Expected: ["elementZero", "elementOne", "elementTwo"] in any order
> Actual: <[elementZero, elementOne, elementTwo]>

How can I assert on data.data to make sure it contains one element that matches my array?

Comment: How about deserialization of `data.data` into `List<List<String>>` and then using methods from List interface?

Answer (score 0):

Try these ones - `"data.data[0][0]"` or `"data.data[0].[0]"`

Comment: Neither of those worked with the code I have above.